# Generic type 'AngularFirestoreDocument<T, DocumentData>' requires 2 type argument(s)

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to declare a variable in my service for an AngularFirestoreDocument ref. When I do so I get this TypeScript error:

> Generic type 'AngularFirestoreDocument' requires 2 type argument(s)

I've seen it done this way in multiple code examples and can't figure out why I'm getting this error. It does compile okay.

Versions:

- angular: 6.0.2
- angularfire2: 5.0.0-rc.10
- firebase: 5.0.4

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

@Injectable()
export class GiftListService {
  giftListRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<GiftList>;
```

Comment: are Imports ok? Import { AngularFirestoreDocument}

Comment: @DiegoVenâncio Yes imports look correct. I edited my post to include imports.

Comment: In app.module do you put all correct imports[     AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
AngularFirestoreModule,]: ?

Answer (score 0):

Try testing it with `giftListRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>` Below is the current definition of `AngularFirestoreDocument` so if yours is different then you need to do a fresh npm install. The culprit is probably typescript version.

```
(alias) class AngularFirestoreDocument<T = { [field: string]: any; }>
```

Comment: I also get the error if I define it as AngularFirestoreDocument<any>. Where can I find the file that has that definition? Also, are you saying it's the version of Typescript that is the problem, or that I have outdated firebase type definitions and need to do a fresh npm install of firebase? Thanks!